# Could a non-injected field lead to race condition in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, race-condition

I tried to use State Pattern in my code. But I can't figure out if this lead to race condition with Spring. Here `active` `stop` `restart`have different implemention. which implemention will be performed depends on what `currentInt` was set by calling `setCurrentInt`. How can I deal with this problem, if yes.

```
@Component
public class StateService {

  //3 states
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("notActivatedState")
  private ActiveState notActivatedState;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("stoppedState")
  private ActiveState stoppedState;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("inUseState")
  private ActiveState inUseState;
  //current state
  private Integer currentInt;



  //Interface which was delegated to perform an act. It is not @Autowired, could there be some problem when multiple requests set currentInt to different values ? 
  private ActiveState currentState;




  public void activate(BdCorp bdCorp) {
    currentState.activate(bdCorp);
  }

  public void stop(BdCorp bdCorp) {
    currentState.stop(bdCorp);
  }

  public void restart(BdCorp bdCorp) {
    currentState.restart(bdCorp);
  }


  public void setCurrentInt(Integer currentInt) {
    this.currentInt = currentInt;
    if (currentInt == 1) {
      this.currentState = notActivatedState;
    }
    if (currentInt == 2) {
      this.currentState = inUseState;
    }
    if (currentInt == 3) {
      this.currentState = stoppedState;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have concurrency problem when currentIn is changed between assigning currentState.

Instead define e.g. [ThreadLocal](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html) for the currentInt and introduce a getter for the current state rather than property.

```
private ThreadLocal<Integer> currentIntStorage = new ThreadLocal<>();

private ActiveState getCurrentState() {
    Integer currentInt = myThreadLocal.get();
    if (currentInt == 1) {
      return notActivatedState;
    }
    else if (currentInt == 2) {
      return inUseState;
    }
    else if (currentInt == 3) {
      return stoppedState;
    }

    return null;
}
```

and use it

```
public void activate(BdCorp bdCorp) {
  getCurrentState().activate(bdCorp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I also found  a solution by using @Scope("prototype") upper `StateService` class,thus every request was processed by different `stateService` instance.This can prevent concurrency problem as well,am I right?@StanislavL